# Style Binding using "style." syntax to Child elements in Angular

Tags: angular, angular8

Is it possible to apply any styling to child components using the `style.` syntax in Angular (I'm running Angular 8). For example:

```
<div class="col-8 kt-padding-l-10" [style.fill]="visitor | vcolor">
    <div>{{ visitor?.id?.substr(0,6) }}</div>
    <div>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" class="kt-svg-icon">
            <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" >
                <rect x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24"/>
                <path d="M21,12.0829584 C20.6747915,12.0283988 20.3407122,12 20,12 C16.6862915,12 14,14.6862915 14,18 C14,18.3407122 14.0283988,18.6747915 14.0829584,19 L5,19 C3.8954305,19 3,18.1045695 3,17 L3,8 C3,6.8954305 3.8954305,6 5,6 L19,6 C20.1045695,6 21,6.8954305 21,8 L21,12.0829584 Z M18.1444251,7.83964668 L12,11.1481833 L5.85557487,7.83964668 C5.4908718,7.6432681 5.03602525,7.77972206 4.83964668,8.14442513 C4.6432681,8.5091282 4.77972206,8.96397475 5.14442513,9.16035332 L11.6444251,12.6603533 C11.8664074,12.7798822 12.1335926,12.7798822 12.3555749,12.6603533 L18.8555749,9.16035332 C19.2202779,8.96397475 19.3567319,8.5091282 19.1603533,8.14442513 C18.9639747,7.77972206 18.5091282,7.6432681 18.1444251,7.83964668 Z" fill="#00000" />
                <circle fill="#00000" opacity="0.3" cx="19.5" cy="17.5" r="2.5"/>
            </g>
        </svg>
        yehia@salam.com
</div>
```

What i want is to style all elements that has a `fill` attribute under the `g` element, if i did in pure css it would be:

```
g [fill]{
   fill: red; /* or in my case the visitor variable with the vcolor pipe */
}
```

It looks like I can't do it but though to double check, the other solution is to add the `[style.fill]="visitor | vcolor"` for each component like the `circle` and `path`, but thats very redundant. What are my options? Creating a separate component as well would be the last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `:ng-deep` to pierce through child component's styles and apply them, so in this component's `scss` try adding this to the top:

```
:host { // host to say for this component
  &::ng-deep {
    g[fill] {
      fill: red;
    }
  }
}
```

You may need another `::ng-deep` but that should definitely get you started.

Comment: but problem is that fill color is dynamic and coming from a variable in the component